# PostgreSQL query returning incorrect records when a column in the ORDER_BY clause has null values?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, subquery

I have a query that fetches all Invoices with it's latest Payment. The subquery orders by different columns and will not always return the true latest payment.

I think I have narrowed down the problem to the `ORDER_BY` clause, because all the Invoices that have a Payment that is not the true latest one are those whose Payments have `null` data in some of the columns that are mentioned in the `ORDER_BY` clause.

Query:

```
SELECT invoices.*, 
      last_payments.id AS last_payment_payment_id,
      last_payments.payment_type AS last_payment_payment_type,
      last_payments.amount_cents AS last_payment_amount_cents,
      last_payments.date_approved AS last_payment_date_approved,
      last_payments.date_created AS last_payment_date_created,
      last_payments.status AS last_payment_status,
      last_payments.status_detail AS last_payment_status_detail
      FROM "invoices"
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (invoice_id) * FROM payments
      ORDER BY payments.invoice_id,
      payments.date_approved DESC, payments.date_created desc
      ) AS last_payments
      ON last_payments.invoice_id = invoices.id
```

Example of Invoice with **correct** last_payment

*payment_id, invoice_id, date_approved, date_created*

```
[
 [46, 184, nil, Wed, 09 Mar 2022 12:05:19 -03 -03:00],
 [47, 184, nil, Wed, 09 Mar 2022 12:05:22 -03 -03:00] # correct record returned
]
```

Example of Invoice with **incorrect** last_payment

*payment_id, invoice_id, date_approved, date_created*

```
[
 [9, 159,  nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 11:11:46 -03 -03:00],
 [10, 159, nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 11:17:46 -03 -03:00],
 [11, 159, nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 11:19:06 -03 -03:00],
 [12, 159, nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 11:24:07 -03 -03:00],
 [13, 159, nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 11:36:00 -03 -03:00],
 [14, 159, nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 11:37:47 -03 -03:00],
 [15, 159, nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 11:45:39 -03 -03:00],
 [16, 159, nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 11:49:10 -03 -03:00],
 [17, 159, nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 11:52:54 -03 -03:00],
 [18, 159, nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 11:54:24 -03 -03:00],
 [19, 159, nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 11:55:23 -03 -03:00],
 [20, 159, nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 11:57:30 -03 -03:00],
 [21, 159, nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 12:00:14 -03 -03:00],
 [22, 159, nil, Fri, 04 Mar 2022 12:42:53 -03 -03:00], # incorrect record returned
 [29, 159, Mon, 07 Mar 2022 10:03:48 -03 -03:00, Mon, 07 Mar 2022 10:03:48 -03 -03:00] # should be this one instead
]
```

So I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with the records with `null` values being put first, but I quite don't understand why. If that is indeed the cause, can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: What is going on is you have read the documentation. See [Order by](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY): 'If NULLS LAST is specified, null values sort after all non-null values; if NULLS FIRST is specified, null values sort before all non-null values. If neither is specified, the default behavior is NULLS LAST when ASC is specified or implied, and NULLS FIRST when DESC is specified (thus, the default is to act as though nulls are larger than non-nulls).'

Comment: Oops that should have been 'not read the documentation', my turn not to read. The way to deal with this is to [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to turn the `NULL`  values into a placeholder value.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the link to the docs.